# XCode Code Snippets, entering each token only once

Tags: xcode, code-snippets, xcode6.1

I am using XCode 6.1, and I have the following code snippet:

```
    var <#InstanceFieldName#> : <#INSTANCE_FIELD_TYPE#> = <#INSTANCE_FIELD_INIT#>;

    func get<#INSTANCE_FIELD_CAMEL_CASE#>() -> <#INSTANCE_FIELD_TYPE#>
    {
        return <#InstanceFieldName#>;
    }

    func set<#INSTANCE_FIELD_CAMEL_CASE#>(<#InstanceFieldName#>_param : <#INSTANCE_FIELD_TYPE#>)
    {
        self.<#InstanceFieldName#> = <#InstanceFieldName#>_param;
    }
```

My issue is that I want to only have to type in the value for <#InstanceFieldName#> once, and have all 5 instances of <#InstanceFieldName#> be populated with that data. PHPStorm's Live Templates come with this functionality by default. Is there a way to make XCode's code snippets do this as well?